# Retrieving Data from firebase database (Working in console but doesnt work in code)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I want to retrieve my data from my database based on the current login user, my database is nested like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNx9h.jpg

I tried my current code in the console, it is working and show the data correctly, but i dont know why when i use the code in my JS file, it doesnt work. Can anyone tell me why..

`My code demo with HTML and JS : https://jsfiddle.net/jyeeyap/7ks2r89t/4/`

When i use my code to load is shows this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/34OXZ.jpg

When i use console : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT3nF.jpg

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the position of certain code in the JS file, the question is solved.